Nautilus removed "Star" feature from context menu
I've been trying so hard to find a solution, it seems that Nautilus removed the "Star" feature from the context menu so when you right click a file you won't be able to see "Star" in Gnome.
I'm using Linux Mint 22 with Gnome 46.
Okay, so i created a script to star files and add it to Nautilus
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

then I created a new script file
touch ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/StarFile

I edited the file with the following content:
#!/bin/bash
gio set "$1" metadata::trusted true

I made the script executable:
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/StarFile

Then finally I restarted Nautilus:
nautilus -q

Right Click shows a Scripts -> StarFile
Image that shows Scripts integrated with context menu
Image that shows StarFile feature added
But the problem the file doesn't get starred at all, so I changed the script content to the following:
#!/bin/bash
gio set "$1" metadata::favorite true

gio info File.txt
display name: File.txt
edit name: File.txt
name: File.txt
type: regular
size:  282
uri: file:///home/x/File.txt
local path: /home/x/File.txt
unix mount: /dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
attributes:
  standard::type: 1
  standard::is-hidden: FALSE
  standard::is-backup: FALSE
  standard::is-symlink: FALSE
  standard::name: File.txt
  standard::display-name: File.txt
  standard::edit-name: File.txt
  standard::copy-name: File.txt
  standard::icon: text-plain, text-x-generic, text-plain-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic
  standard::content-type: text/plain
  standard::fast-content-type: text/plain
  standard::size: 282
  standard::allocated-size: 4096
  standard::symbolic-icon: text-plain-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, text-plain, text-x-generic
  etag::value: 1729537107:404526:404526833
  id::file: l2050:6608283
  id::filesystem: l2050
  access::can-read: TRUE
  access::can-write: TRUE
  access::can-execute: FALSE
  access::can-delete: TRUE
  access::can-trash: TRUE
  access::can-rename: TRUE
  time::modified: 1729537107
  time::modified-usec: 404526
  time::access: 1729537107
  time::access-usec: 391526
  time::changed: 1729537107
  time::changed-usec: 412527
  time::created: 1729537107
  time::created-usec: 391526
  time::modified-nsec: 404526833
  time::access-nsec: 391526345
  time::created-nsec: 391526345
  time::changed-nsec: 412527133
  unix::device: 2050
  unix::inode: 6608283
  unix::mode: 33204
  unix::nlink: 1
  unix::uid: 1000
  unix::gid: 1000
  unix::rdev: 0
  unix::block-size: 4096
  unix::blocks: 8
  unix::is-mountpoint: FALSE
  owner::user: x
  owner::user-real: x
  owner::group: x
  metadata::favorite: yes
  metadata::trusted: true
x@x-laptop:~$ 

All this didn't work, so I edited the script little bit to get into the Real exact file path:
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$(realpath "$1")
echo "File to star: $FILE"
gio set "$FILE" metadata::trusted true
gio set "$FILE" metadata::favorite true

It didn't work as well.
I tried on terminal with many combinations as well none worked.
gio set File.txt metadata::favorite true
gio set File.txt metadata::favorite yes
gio set /home/x/File.txt metadata::favorite true
gio set /home/x/File.txt metadata::favorite yes
gio set "/home/x/File.txt" metadata::favorite true
gio set "/home/x/File.txt" metadata::favorite yes
gio set "/home/x/File.txt" "metadata::favorite" true
gio set "/home/x/File.txt" "metadata::favorite" yes

None worked out.
What I'm missing?
